# How to define a function that expects a stack as an argument? (full question below)

Tags: python, function, data-structures, stack, queue

Can anyone help me with this question? I'm fairly new to coding so help would be much appreciated

Qn: Define a function that expects a stack as an argument. The function builds and returns an instance of **LinkedQueue** that contains the elements in the stack. The function assumes that the stack has the interface described in the previous stack section. The function's postconditions are that the stack is left in the same state as it was before the function was called, and that the queue's front element is the one at the top of the stack.

Comment: What is a stack in python? A list? A deque? A custom implementation?

Answer (score 0):

looks school work :D
for a stack you can only push/pop on it.
1st, pop elements, 1 by 1, to create the linkedList, and push the popped elements to a reversed stack.
2nd, pop everything from the reversed stack and push back into original stack.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a way to copy your stack:

```
def build_queue_from_stack(stack: Stack):
    temp = stack.copy()
    linked_queue = LinkedQueue()
    while stack:
        linked_queue.append(stack.pop())
    return linked_queue
```